# while loop increment value not working inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$i = 5;
while($i > 0){
echo "
<input type = 'submit' value = '$i' id = '$i'>
";
$i--;
}
?>
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
var i = 5;
while(i > 0){
$('#'+i).live('click',function(){
alert(i);
});
i--;
}
});
</script>
```

When I click on a button, the javascript should alert the id of the button i clicked.
But which ever button I click on it alerts 0 . I am thinking that the while loops increment value is not working inside the function. What should id do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because some the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures) of the variable `i`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 5;
    while(i > 0){
        (function(idx){
            $('#'+idx).live('click',function(){
                alert(idx);
            });
        })(i)
        i--;
    }
});
```